# How to choose typeface (fonts) for a website in different locales?

Tags: font, typography

Part of a good UX for websites and web applications that support multiple languages is their fonts.

Let's imagine that English is not the default font on the web and another nation has created the web and the internet.

In that case, most websites belong to that nation and show that nation's language as the default language.

Now, in this imaginary world, as an English speaker of a minority, you go to a website that offers your language. You click the drop-down, select your country, and you see this:

[image]

Why, because the developer of that website has no idea that this font is not suitable for the English language on the web.

So, in spite of the relativistic nature of the beauty and suitability of fonts for different use-cases, my question is:

How do you choose/find the most suitable fonts for a locale in a website?

P.S: We are developing a multilingual website/app that needs to support Russian, Arabic, Persian, English, and Turkish. And we want to improve our UI/UX by including fonts that are better than defaults and are more readable to native speakers of those languages.

Comment: What different preferences do you see in those different locales?

The time and effort you think you should put in will depend on the differences you can describe.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What are you trying to say with "assume that English is not the default font on the web"? English is not a font, but a language. And also, a majority of websites is not in English, but other languages. And what you mean with "another nation has created the web and the internet"? What is "the" nation that you take as the one that created it (may I assume USA)? Different parts were developed in different nations. And when you refer to USA and the WWW, you dont have to imagine this, it was developed in another nation.

Comment: Also, I don't see what's the problem with the font in your question. How is this less suitable to display English, than e.g. German, French, Spanish, Italian, Turkish, ...? I assume it is even better suited, because the other languages have additional characters with diacritics or umlauts that are not present in English. Or has it to do that it is a cursive script? And maybe that cursive is not so well taught in the region you refer to? Or is it a purly aesthetic reason? Then it is not so obvious to me and maybe others, why you don't like it.

Comment: Maybe you just wanted to ask how one can choose a font that is suitable for displaying text in other alphabets and scripts, other than Latin?

Comment: In other words, you want to know how to choose/specify/select a font for each language? (i.e. css code) Or are you asking for good fonts for such languages?

Comment: @PabloH, I'm asking for the second reason. I want to make sure that my chosen fonts are at least a good choice for users of that target locale.

Answer (score 11):

I'd use a font family that has been designed to cover as many scripts as possible. That way there is a visual coherence between different language versions of the website (or app or any system).

One such font family is [Noto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts), commissioned by Google and it is licensed in SIL Open Font License. From Wikipedia:

> The Noto fonts cover 150 out of the 154 scripts defined in Unicode version 13.0 (released in March 2020), as well as various syllables and emoji which do not belong to a specific script.

https://fonts.google.com/noto

Comment: I'd edit this answer slightly to include "use a well-designed font family that has been carefully designed to be readable in as many scripts as possible".

Answer (score 4):

Good font providers offer enough information to be able to choose the right font according to its use: platforms (web or desktop), formats and supported languages according its glyphs.

---

*Myfonts.com* in the <kbd>Tech Specs</kbd> tab has information about Supported Languages:

[image]

You can even do a search filtered by required languages:

[image]

<sub>*Sample font [Stenzilla](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/darezd/stenzilla?tab=glyphs)*</sub>

Comment: The question was about telling the difference between usable fonts and suitable fonts; the example font is usable for English, but not suitable for general-purpose English body text.

Comment: The sample font is just an example with no other purpose. The answer is about information regarding support in different languages available from font providers.

Comment: The example of a bad font *in the question* is usable for English, but not suitable for general-purpose English body text.

Comment: @prosfilaes Unstated—and it should be stated—is the assumption that the font will share a similar style across various character-sets, and thus will be suitable for similar purposes. This assumption may be flawed (a font may not be consistent, or consistent stylistic touches might be suitable for a purpose in English but not in another language), but the choice of example font doesn’t really have any bearing on whether it is (fatally) flawed or not. (And if this assumption _is_ flawed, the top-rated answer here suffers from the same assumption.)

Comment: @KRyan I don't see that assumption in the question. It's not a question about similar style; it's about suitability for similar purposes independent of that. The example font shows how a font can be usable for a language but unsuitable for most purposes. Noto will be suitable for most purposes for most languages; Stenzilla and other random fonts from Myfont.com won't, and the question was how to avoid fonts like Stenzilla even if you don't understand the script.

Comment: @prosfilaes I didn’t say it was an assumption in the question—and I explicitly called it _unstated_. Both answers assume that if a font supports multiple languages, it will 1. have a consistent style in each language, and 2. that style will be suitable for the same uses in all languages. Whether any given example is suitable for many uses, as Noto, or only some uses, as Stenzilla, is _completely irrelevant_ to the point that both answers are making: pick a font that suits your purpose in English, and that supports other languages, assuming that it will be consistent and suitable.

Comment: @KRyan Noto and most "font famil[ies] that ha[ve] been designed to cover as many scripts as possible" have a consistent style in each language and are reasonably suitable for the same users in all languages. Stylized fonts for Arabic or other languages may have ASCII characters only to fulfill certain software requirements, and make no attempt to make them match the styling of the main language of the font.

Comment: @prosfilaes OK, *that* is a valid criticism, but it took four back-and-forth exchanges for me to get that point. Don’t focus on the example—that doesn’t matter per se. The focus should be on the suggestion, namely to use the “Supported Languages” section on font listings. If that Supported Languages thing doesn’t actually signify that the font is designed consistently for those languages—as this answer assumes—then that’s a valid critique, but I don’t see how Danielillo was supposed to get that out of any of your prior comments.

Comment: @KRyan What do you mean by "not designed consistently"? The question's example shows that the OP doesn't want perfectly consistent fonts that aren't easily readable. His point is that he's not competent to judge fonts in those scripts; my additional point was that the Latin display of the font may not help.

Comment: @prosfilaes And who is relying solely on the Latin display? Not this answer. It rather points to the Supported Languages for a font to determine whether or not it will be suitable. E.g. if you have a situation where Stenzilla is appropriate in English, it will (this answer asserts) be equally-appropriate in Western European, Central/Eastern European, Baltic, Turkish, Romanian, and Cyrillic languages as well. The unspoken assumption here is that the design of the font is consistent for all languages that it claims to support, and that this will consistently suitable.

Comment: @KRyan The idea that you can look at the Latin display and the Supported Languages and assume a font will be equivalent in all Supported Languages is wrong, because that unspoken assumption is frequently wrong.

Comment: @prosfilaes Yes, I get that now—but you spent 5 comments complaining about how Stenzilla isn’t suitable for body text _instead of saying that_.

Comment: @KRyan No, from the start I was talking about the example font in the question. The first post may not have been clear, but the second one should be clear.

Comment: @prosfilaes I was counting your back-and-forth with Daniello as well as with me, though even then yes, I meant 4 (the second response to me), not 5.

Comment: @KRyan The very first post I made on this question had nothing to do with Stenzilla. Nor did the second, and I'm not sure how that one is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

> And we want to improve our UI/UX by including fonts that are better than defaults and are more readable to native speakers of those languages.

This is fundamentally misguided. If the user is running an OS/browser in their native language, the whole point of its defaults is that they are familiar, readable, and perfectly suitable for presenting text in their native language. As someone not familiar with their language and typography, **you are not going to do better** and you're going to annoy them, **just like** the example with English text in your question. The solution isn't to try to become an expert and do better. The solution is **don't do that**.

The same also applies to your native language, English. Just because you are very familiar with it and have Legitimate Opinions about fonts, doesn't mean you're qualified to override the user's defaults. They may have accessibility needs (visual or cognitive) that you don't and can't understand, motivating whatever defaults they have selected, and overriding that is **hostile UX**. Don't do it.

Comment: Are you implying that setting the font for a website or application to something other than the system default is always hostile UX?

Comment: @flyingfisch: For body/UI text at least, yes.

Comment: You have to at least admit that that is not a mainstream opinion, given the fact that very few applications or websites use default system fonts. this is true even of websites specifically devoted to UX, like nngroup.com

Comment: it's also worth noting that many users don't know how to set their default system fonts, so for the majority of users the font they see was not a conscious decision. In a way, you're just forcing them to be stuck with the font their OS manufacturer picked instead of the one you did.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two things you need to do - **hire an expert** in visual design who is a native of each alphabet you're using, and **do some end user testing**.

**Hire an expert** - This can be a very brief project for someone on UpWork or another freelance site. You describe the look/feel/brand of your application, and they'll suggest fonts that would work.

**End user testing** - You can also use this session to make sure that language, labels, etc make sense. To test the typography style, ask a few questions like, "What are a few words to describe your overall impression of the design?"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should pick a font or font family that has the glyphs that cover the languages in question, so you don't need to pick multiple fonts. (or if you do need multiple fonts, they are mutually consistent between themselves)
You can use different fonts for things like Titles and Headings, but I would say try to make them similar-ish. (Like either same family, or same font style)

I would suggest NOT using Script fonts ... or fonts that you would find on a fancy wedding invitation...or fonts that look Medieval...

I'm not sure what your language is, but, look for a font that is easy to read at the default character size on your site and looks good to you and your testers.

I'm not sure what your site is for or what information is being presented, so that might influence the better font style for presentation.

You might need to/want to run it by someone fluent/native in those languages to make sure that it's not egregiously hideous for your purposes.